# Php code in html not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I want to use this code to get results from my database and show it in html but this is not happening. Getting all weird results and am not able to fix it.

it display } ? >  on my webpage at the end wonder why.And i cannot get any results from my database displayed either.

Database is proper I believe some error in html and php code(php variables in html tags).

```
<?php  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$price = ($row['ISBN']%1000);
echo $price;
<li>
        <div class="book-display-bg">
            <div class="book-display-placeholder">
                <div class="book-display-container">
                    <div class="book-display-centered">
                        <a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  >
                            <img src=''$row['Image_URL_M']'' style='border: 0;' alt=''$row['Book_Title']''/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="book-display-details">
            <div class="book-display-title"><p><a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  title=''$row['Book_Title']'' >$row['Book_Title']</a></p></div>
            <div class="book-display-author"><p>$row['Book_Author']</p></div>
            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_divStock" class="book-display-stock"></div>
            <div class="book-display-price">$price</div>
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder$cphContent1$ctl01$ProductSummary1$DataList1$ctl02$btnBuyNow" value="add to basket" id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_btnBuyNow" title="add to basket" class="ecom-add-basket" />
        </div>        
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you forgot to add echo for the html content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add echo for the li element. You can try following:

```
<?php  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$price = ($row['ISBN']%1000);
echo $price; ?>
<li>
        <div class="book-display-bg">
            <div class="book-display-placeholder">
                <div class="book-display-container">
                    <div class="book-display-centered">
                        <a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  >
                            <img src='<?php echo $row['Image_URL_M']; ?>' style='border: 0;' alt='<?php echo $row['Book_Title']; ?>'/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="book-display-details">
            <div class="book-display-title"><p><a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  title='<?php echo $row['Book_Title']; ?>' ><?php echo $row['Book_Title']; ?></a></p></div>
            <div class="book-display-author"><p><?php echo $row['Book_Author']; ?></p></div>
            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_divStock" class="book-display-stock"></div>
            <div class="book-display-price"><?php echo $price; ?></div>
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder$cphContent1$ctl01$ProductSummary1$DataList1$ctl02$btnBuyNow" value="add to basket" id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_btnBuyNow" title="add to basket" class="ecom-add-basket" />
        </div>        
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li><?php
}
?>
```

or You can do it this way:

```
<?php  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$price = ($row['ISBN']%1000);
echo $price;
echo '<li>
        <div class="book-display-bg">
            <div class="book-display-placeholder">
                <div class="book-display-container">
                    <div class="book-display-centered">
                        <a href="product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html"  >
                            <img src="' . $row['Image_URL_M'] . '" style="border: 0;" alt="$row[\'Book_Title\']"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="book-display-details">
            <div class="book-display-title"><p><a href="product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html"  title="' . $row['Book_Title'] . '" >' . $row['Book_Title'] . '</a></p></div>
            <div class="book-display-author"><p> ' .$row['Book_Author'] . '</p></div>
            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_divStock" class="book-display-stock"></div>
            <div class="book-display-price">' . $price . '</div>
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder$cphContent1$ctl01$ProductSummary1$DataList1$ctl02$btnBuyNow" value="add to basket" id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_btnBuyNow" title="add to basket" class="ecom-add-basket" />
        </div>        
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>';
}
?>
```

hope it helped

Comment: should i add echo for the image element also?

Comment: Which method are you using? method on top or the other one

Comment: I am using the other method

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made the changes in the code. You can use that. I just concatenated the variable with the HTML code in the echo

Comment: Thanks. How do we use php variables in mysqli query?    $result = mysqli_query($con,"((SELECT * FROM bx_books where Book_Title like '%$search%') union (SELECT * FROM bx_books where Book_Author like '%$search%') union (SELECT * FROM bx_books where ISBN like '%$search%'))");        i want to use $search in query

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(`COL1`,`COL2`,`COL3`) VALUES ('" .$PHPVAR1 . "','" . $PHPVAR2 . "','" . $PHPVAR3 ."')"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56412/discussion-between-sankalp-srivastava-and-user2598085).

Comment: my net has gone down.. i will get in touch as soon as its up

Comment: and it does not work even without wamp  even a simple echo statement

Comment: it won't work without wamp as you need to have apache running and responding to compile the php.

Answer (score 1):

Please do use open and close braces correctly.

If you want to use the HTMl code in php then all you have to do is echo

for example:

```
<?php  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<div class='book-display-centered'>{$row['Book_Author']}</div>"
}
?>
```

And since you have lot of data in html you can use it like this

```
 <?php  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     ?>
         <div class='book-display-centered'><?php echo $row['Book_Author'] ?></div>
    <?php 
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must echo html content or close php tag before them

Try this:

```
<?php  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$price = ($row['ISBN']%1000);
echo $price;
?>
<li>
        <div class="book-display-bg">
            <div class="book-display-placeholder">
                <div class="book-display-container">
                    <div class="book-display-centered">
                        <a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  >
                            <img src="<?php echo $row['Image_URL_M']?>" style='border: 0;' alt=" <?php echo $row['Book_Title']?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="book-display-details">
            <div class="book-display-title"><p><a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  title="<?php echo $row['Book_Title'] ?>" > <?php echo $row['Book_Title']?></a></p></div>
            <div class="book-display-author"><p><?php echo $row['Book_Author'] ?></p></div>
            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_divStock" class="book-display-stock"></div>
            <div class="book-display-price"><?php echo $price ?></div>
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder$cphContent1$ctl01$ProductSummary1$DataList1$ctl02$btnBuyNow" value="add to basket" id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_btnBuyNow" title="add to basket" class="ecom-add-basket" />
        </div>        
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code...
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

```
$price = ($row['ISBN']%1000);
echo $price;
?>
<li>
    <div class="book-display-bg">
        <div class="book-display-placeholder">
            <div class="book-display-container">
                <div class="book-display-centered">
                    <a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  >
                        <img src=''$row['Image_URL_M']'' style='border: 0;' alt=''$row['Book_Title']''/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="book-display-details">
        <div class="book-display-title"><p><a href='product/taqatu-niran-min-yaumiyat-al-intifada-as-suriya-9789953892368-(105523).html'  title=''$row['Book_Title']'' >$row['Book_Title']</a></p></div>
        <div class="book-display-author"><p>$row['Book_Author']</p></div>
        <div id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_divStock" class="book-display-stock"></div>
        <div class="book-display-price">$price</div>
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder$cphContent1$ctl01$ProductSummary1$DataList1$ctl02$btnBuyNow" value="add to basket" id="ctl00_ctl00_CMSContentMasterPlaceHolder_cphContent1_ctl01_ProductSummary1_DataList1_ctl02_btnBuyNow" title="add to basket" class="ecom-add-basket" />
    </div>        
    <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```